# Python3 iterate through a list and print in a certain sequence/combination

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration, sequence

I have a list of words I want to iterate through and print a specific order.

For example:

```py
words = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'pear', 'berry']
```

I want the sequence to be like this:

```
apple.apple.apple.apple
apple.apple.apple.banana
apple.apple.banana.apple
apple.banana.apple.apple
banana.apple.apple.apple
banana.apple.apple.banana
banana.apple.banana.apple
```

I hope you get the gist of it. But it would basically print out every combination that's possible in a four word pattern like above.

```py
words = []
with open('words') as my_file:
    words = my_file.read().splitlines()
for i in range(len(words)):
    if i+4 <= len(words):
        print(".".join(words[i:i+4]))

for j in range(1, len(words)):
    if j+4 <= len(words):
        print(".".join(words[j:j+4]))
```

This was really close as it did print the words in the order i was looking for but it didn't go through every combination like i was hoping for.

Answer (score -1):

In terms of indices, your expected result looks like this:

```
0000
0001
0010
0100
1000
1001
1010
1100
1101
1110
1111
...
```

Let `words` be the list of words and `n` be the number of elements for each sequence `yield`ed from our function. We need three iterators:

- One to iterate from 1 through `n`; let this be `i`
- One to iterate from `n` down to 1; let this be `j`
- One to iterate from 1 up to `j`; let this be `k`

Visual explanation:

```css
table {
  font-family: monospace;
}

td[rowspan] {
  position: relative;
}

td[rowspan] > span {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.j, td:nth-last-child(3) > span {
  background: #ddd;
}

.k, td:nth-last-child(2) > span {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">i</th>
      <th scope="col"><span class="j">j</span></th>
      <th scope="col"><span class="k">k</span></th>
      <th scope="col">product</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>0</span></td>
      <td><span>0</span></td>
      <td><span>0</span></td>
      <td><span>0000</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="10"><span>1</span></td>
      <td rowspan="4"><span>4</span></td>
      <td><span>1</span></td>
      <td><span><span class="j">0</span>00<span class="k">1</span></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>2</span></td>
      <td><span><span class="j">0</span>0<span class="k">1</span>0</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>3</span></td>
      <td><span><span class="j">0</span><span class="k">1</span>00</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>4</span></td>
      <td><span><span class="j k">1</span>000</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3"><span>3</span></td>
      <td><span>1</span></td>
      <td><span>1<span class="j">0</span>0<span class="k">1</span></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>2</span></td>
      <td><span>1<span class="j">0</span><span class="k">1</span>0</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>3</span></td>
      <td><span>1<span class="j k">1</span>00</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"><span>2</span></td>
      <td><span>1</span></td>
      <td><span>11<span class="j">0</span><span class="k">1</span></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>2</span></td>
      <td><span>11<span class="j k">1</span>0</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>1</span></td>
      <td><span>1</span></td>
      <td><span>111<span class="j k">1</span></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Implementation:

```py
def product(words, n):
  def to_words(indices):
    return tuple(words[index] for index in indices)

  # The (0, 0, 0, 0) case
  # Tuple does not support item assignment so we'll have to use list.
  current = [0] * n
  yield to_words(current)

  for i in range(1, n + 1):
    for j in range(n, 0, -1):
      # (0, 0, 0, 0) -> (0, 0, 0, 1)
      current[-1] += 1
      yield to_words(current)
      
      for k in range(1, j):
        # j = 4, k = 1
        # (0, 0, 0, 1) -> (0, 0, 1, 0)
        # ...
        # j = 3, k = 2
        # (1, 0, 1, 0) -> (1, 1, 0, 0)
        # j = 2, k = 1
        # (1, 1, 0, 1) -> (1, 1, 1, 0)
        # ...
        current[-k - 1], current[-k] = current[-k], current[-k - 1]
        yield to_words(current)
```

Try it:

```
words = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'pear', 'berry']

print(*product(words, 4))

'''
('apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple')
('apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'banana')
('apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'apple')
('apple', 'banana', 'apple', 'apple')
('banana', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple')
('banana', 'apple', 'apple', 'banana')
('banana', 'apple', 'banana', 'apple')
('banana', 'banana', 'apple', 'apple')
('banana', 'banana', 'apple', 'banana')
('banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'apple')
('banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana')
...
'''
```

Comment: So this did work up until a certain point. It stopped relatively short and I'm not sure why

Comment: @CalebSchilling What do you mean by "*stopped relatively short*"? I tried it locally and it printed 41 results, in the exact order you required.

Answer (score -1):

As Samwise said, use [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```py
from itertools import product

words = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "pear", "berry"]
for i in product(words,repeat=4):
    print(".".join(i))
```

Comment: Use: `for word in product(words,repeat=4)` rather than typing `words` for 4 times.

Comment: ok, thank you, I'm not very familiar with the product package yet.